# angularjs read from properties file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, properties

In angularJS how can I read a value from a properties file?

```
connection.properties:  

url="http://localhost:8080"  
user= "me"  
get= "GET"  
post= "POST"
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('testing',[]);  
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope,$http) {    
     $http({    
        url: connection.properties.url  ,
        method: connection.properties.get,  
        params: {user: connection.properties.user})        
     });
});
```

Comment: @patxy connection.properties is a file that lives on my server.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `connection.properties` is a file that lives on your web server, then you simply need to do this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('connection.properties').then(function (response) {
    console.log('a is ', response.data.a);
    console.log('b is ', response.data.b);
  });
});
```

You can see an example here:

**http://plnkr.co/edit/3Ne3roFOwcfVmg2mgnUr?p=preview**

Comment: can you provide more detail how i actually get `connection.properties`?

Comment: very nice will test this out shortly.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Sorry, gave you some bad info... see my latest update.

Comment: kindly tell me where to keep connection.properties file?? do I need to keep in webApp folder or i can keep it in any local folder ??

Comment: @Langdon I'm getting a 404 (Not Found) message even if my file is at the main directory.

Comment: @razorblade What web server?  Perhaps it's not configured to serve `.properties` files (a common problem with IIS).

Comment: @Langdon I'm using this method on my service class but I'm using other $http method, so I have two $http methods one for my properties file an the other one for my rest services, but both are executing asynchronously, have you ever been there?

Comment: this does not work for me, $http.get('connection.properties') is not getting executed before, hence all the values in the properties file is showing undefined. I have provided a work around for achieving this.  hope that is helpful for some of you

Comment: @Baranir it works fine, but the values won't be available immediately after the `$http.get` call... you have to wait until the callback is executed.  your method uses global data, which isn't the best approach, as those values can easily be clobbered by other scripts.

Comment: The example in this linnk does not work, `unexpected start tag token ....` error.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way is to

1. create a js file named

   "config.js"  (lets assume in the path scripts/config/config.js)

   config.js:

   var test1="http://testurl.com"
   var test2="globalconstant"
2. In the html page include this config.js at the top (above the main
   controller.js): `**<script..
   src="./scripts/config/config.js"></st>**`
3. In the controller make the following change:

   MainController.js:
   $scope.appUrl = test1;
   $scope.appConstant = test2;

Answer (score 0):

Langdon's answer loads the content of the properties file for me but the value inside the properties are not accessible to me in the format of `response.data.a` and `response.data.b` etc and always returns `undefined`. For the value to be available to me I have to extract the content of the properties file and to turn them into JSON format before I can use it. A modification of the above proposed solution would be such:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function ($scope, $http) {
    function extractProperties(data){
        const lines = data.split("\n");
        properties = {}

        for (const l of lines) {
            const line = l.trim();
            if (!line || line[0] === '#') {
                continue;
            }
            const keyValue = line.split("=");
            const key = keyValue[0].trim();
            const value = keyValue[1].trim();
            properties[key] = value

        }

        return properties;
    }

    $http.get('connection.properties').then(function (response) {
        const properties = extractProperties(response.data);
        console.log('URL is ', properties.url);
        console.log('User is ', properties.user);
    });
});
```