# Angularjs - $http.get of properties file always returns 404

Tags: angularjs

Maybe I'm doing something wrong here because I can not get this work. am I missing something?

**services.js**

```
$http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : 'angular.properties'
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("good");
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("error: " + data); // It's printing this.
});
```

**angular.properties**

```
{ 
    "url": "http://localhost", 
    "port": "",
    "default_language": "es" 
}
```

**app structure**

[image: app structure]

**Error**

[image]

**Gruntfile.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    connect: { 
      server: {
        options: {
          port: 9000,
          base: 'app/'
        }
      }
    },
    watch: { 
      project: {
        files: ['app/**/*.js', 'app/**/*.html', 'app/**/*.json', 'app/**/*.css'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      }
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect', 'watch']);

};
```

**ANSWER**

The content of the folder 'app' is what I should put on my server. So I just need the content of app, AND my angular.properties was out of this folder. That's the mistake. Now is working :) The correct structure of this is:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by `angular.properties`?

Comment: a simple properties file. like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100225/angularjs-read-from-properties-file

Comment: @skubski url seems same in console error..

Comment: @PankajParkar you are right!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `main.js` is your service so you're actually starting your site from `/module` and not `/app` which means your `.properties` file exist in the directory below the root of the website.

If you move your `angular.properties` file into the `module` directory, your original code should work.

Comment: The content of the folder 'app' is what I should put on my server. So I just need the content of app, AND my angular.properties was out of this folder. That's the mistake. Now is working :) Thanks for expand the vision to dealing with this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to define angular.properties as a value. You can also declare it as a constant but then you can only inject it into controllers and services.

```
angular.module(NAME).value('properties', { 
    "url": "http://localhost", 
    "port": "",
    "default_language": "es" 
});
```

This way you can easily inject it into your service and then consume it in the call

```
$http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : properties.url
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("good");
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("error: " + data); // It's printing this.
});
```