# Reading an external properties file from Angular

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to read a properties file from angular js which resides outside the web server? I have read it in some posts that it is not possible to read the file that resides outside the web server.

I can think of one way, where I can create a java service which will read the properties file and which can be invoked by angular to get the properties. But I am not sure if its the best way to do it..

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a way to read a file on a different webserver (i.e. Different domain) which gives you cross origin issues? Or are you looking for a way to read a file from a file system?

Comment: I am looking for a way to read from the file system..

Comment: See answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100225/angularjs-read-from-properties-file/54073326#54073326 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945760/how-to-read-java-property-file-in-angularjs/54007852#54007852