# How to read Java property file in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way to read a properties file from angularjs which resides outside the web server?

like in java the property file deployed out of the project but we can read those file in our project as filter.properties in this way any solution is there in angularJS.

I tried like this but getting undefined.

**filter.properties:**

```
key1=value1 
key2=value2
```

**sampleController.js**

```
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', []);
    app.controller('sampleController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('filter.properties').then(function (response) {
        console.log('a is ', JSON.stringify(response.data.key1));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to access properties files in angularjs.

Like every files properties file is a file with .properties extension.
Since java properties files are key value pair separated by `=` in a single line.

So we can convert a properties file into javascript object by iterating each lines in properties file and split-ing it with `=` symbol and storing it as javascript object which will help to access it quickly.

Here is its javascript implementation

```
function extractProperties(propertiesFileContents){
  var keyValuePairs =propertiesFileContents.split("\n");
  properties ={}
  for (i = 0; i < keyValuePairs.length; i++) {
     var keyValueArr=keyValuePairs[i].trim().split("=");
     var key=keyValueArr[0];
     var value=keyValueArr[1];
     properties[key]=value
  }
  return properties;
}
```

Based on your code here iam adding a [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/X8Ywsh/) here hope this may help you

Comment: Thanks for quick replay let me try.

Comment: is any way to read that property file from localhost? in angularJS

Comment: @ShivaGoudA are you working on which type of application

Comment: spring mvc project

Comment: You can try following links for reference 1 [Returning a file from spring controller ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers) and 2  [loading a property file into controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333363/loading-a-properties-file-from-java-package)

Comment: is it possible to call from controller.js

Comment: yes you can call the controller for properties file in angular.

Comment: can we have chat box

Comment: can you provide how to call localhost property file in JS

Comment: localhost property file i did n't get you

Comment: can we have chat box?

Comment: maintain a file in our local system and read that file using angular controller...because of we want to call hard codings are there those are move to one file and read those key and values

Comment: Yes for sure create a chat

Answer (score 2):

Samuel J Mathew's solution works for me, but the properties file I have to deal with have multiple empty lines in the file, together with lines commented out, and sometimes with white spaces around the `=` sign. So I have to add some checks to handle these situations. The modified result is such, hopefully will be useful to those working with a more complex properties file:

```
function extractProperties(data){
    const keyValuePairs = data.split("\n");
    properties = {}

    for (var i = 0; i < keyValuePairs.length; i++) {
      const keyValuePair = keyValuePairs[i].trim();
      if (!keyValuePair || keyValuePair[0] === '#') {
        continue;
      }
      const keyValueArr = keyValuePair.split("=");
      const key = keyValueArr[0].trim();
      const value = keyValueArr[1].trim();
      properties[key] = value
    }

    return properties;
  }
```